# Display image on page using XML & XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

**XML Database League XSL**
I Will Like to Created a *Simple Database* League with Extensible Markup Language (**XML**) And Extensible Stylesheet Language (**XSL**). the purpose is to develop a *SimpleCode Database League* to can display in a simple form to generate a ***League***, ***Football Clubs*** / *Leagues* and *Tournaments Information*.

**The based code created**:
**XML File**:

```
<League>
<Team id="Name_Team_id">
   <Team_Name>Manchester United</Team_Name>
   <description>Info of the Team Database League Premier League</description>
   <City>Londres </City>
   <Stadium>Teatro de los Sueños </Stadium>
   <Players>
      <person>
      <first_name>W. Rooney</first_name>
      <Country_birth>Inglaterra</Country_birth>  
      <Position>DC, FW</Position>
      </person> 
    </Players>
</Team>
</League>
```

**XSL File:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

<!-- Definimos Template Root de la hoja completa -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>XML Database League XSL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>XML Database League</h1>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="League/Team">
            <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Fin Template Root de la hoja completa -->

<!-- Definimos Template XSL & Buscamos Los Teams del XML -->
<xsl:template match="Team">
  <div>
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="Team_Name"/>
        (
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        )
    </h2>

<!-- Buscamos descripcion de los Teams del XML -->
    <xsl:for-each select="description">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>

<!-- Definimos & Buscamos Los Players del XML, Generamos Tabla Estadisticas -->
  <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#2282b1">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="Players/person">
      <tr bgcolor="#a9b8c2">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="first_name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Country_birth"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Position"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
<!-- Fin de Los Players del XML -->

  </div>

<!-- Fin Template XSL match="Team"  -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** THe Code Above its ok and can test in that link:
http://xml.we11.net/ligapremier.xml but when used code to post image like: **Logo Teams**, **Players** its **does Not Display or Show pictures?**... 
for example the code of **XML with Image** of Colombia, **Just for Test**:

File **XML with Id Team** and **Image Support**.

```
<League>
<Team id="ManchesterUnited" img="colombia.png">
   <Team_Name>Manchester United</Team_Name>
   <description>Info of the Team Database League Premier League</description>
   <City>Londres </City>
   <Stadium>Teatro de los Sueños </Stadium>
   <Players>
      <person>
      <first_name>W. Rooney</first_name>
      <Country_birth>Inglaterra</Country_birth>  
      <Position>DC, FW</Position>
      </person> 
    </Players>
</Team>
</League>
```

**Why Not Display the image with the Team id?**
i am lost with the code...
any **help** or Any **Suggestion** or **Collaborator** are Welcome…

Can Test in the link… not Display image of team! :(

Thanks in Advance for you help!

Learning **Xml** & **Xsl** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to produce an `<img>` with the `@src` pointing to the image from the `Team/@img`:

It is easier and more succinct to use an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) for the `@src` value, like below:

```
<xsl:template match="Team">
  <div>
    <h2>
      <img src="{@img}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="Team_Name"/>
      (
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      )
    </h2>
```

You could also use the more verbose `xsl:attribute`:

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="@img"/>
  <xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Of course, you will need to figure out how to construct the correct URL to the image if the relative path from the XML file does not resolve.

For instance:

```
<img src="http://xml.we11.net/images/{@img}"/>
```